# Is there any way to use existing AWS ELB for ingress in Kubernetes for airflow helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Planning to host airflow on Kubernetes (EKS), using the official helm chart. But the problem is it doesn't provide any way to use existing ELB. And as soon as I delete the release, it deletes the ELB created for ingress. Is there any way i can pass the elb address and create ingress upon it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TargetGroupBinding to connect a service to an existing load balander.

```
apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: my-tgb
spec:
  serviceRef:
    name: <airflow-service-name>
    port: 80
  targetGroupARN: <arn-to-targetGroup>
```

Example taken from here:
https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/targetgroupbinding/targetgroupbinding/#sample-yaml

Comment: this one worked, but only when i have enabled ingress in helm chart. as soon as i disable ingress from helm chart , it stops working giving 504 timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to retain the existing resource during the recreation, You could use below annotation in the template files to avoid helm to recreate.

```
helm.sh/resource-policy=keep
```

Something like this, This would retain the istio-ingressgateway NLB resource.

```
kubectl annotate svc -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway helm.sh/resource-policy=keep
```

Comment: is there a way to pass the ELB address to the config? so that I can create ELB manually and then, later on, ask helm or Kubernetes (either using helm) or using native kubectl apply to create ingress upon it.

Comment: I don't think you can place the existing ELB resource in the spec as LoadBalancer service doesn't have that field.  Instead you could create NodePort Service and manage the LB target groups accordingly with cluster nodes.